# accessing MySQL database in XAMPP through flask framework

Tags: python, mysql, xampp

I just started looking into Flask framework for a pet project of mine, and so, I have been working on a tutorial in envato tutsplus. I build the database in MySQL present in the XAMPP server and I am trying to access it, but I do not know how to go about doing it.

I get this error in the chrome console `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)`. I have already started XAMPP prior to executing this code.

I know that the `@app.route('/signUp',methods=['POST','GET'])` is the key method to look into and also the key lies in `app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST']`. I thought that putting localhost as a value would work, but that is not the case and so I tried different values like `http://localhost:80` etc but that does not seem to work. What is it that I am missing? Please help me out

Here is the backend code :

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, json
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
from werkzeug import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash

mysql = MySQL()
app = Flask(__name__)

# MySQL configurations
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = ''
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = 'BucketList'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = 'localhost'
mysql.init_app(app)

@app.route('/')
def main():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/showSignUp')
def showSignUp():
    return render_template('signup.html')

@app.route('/signUp',methods=['POST','GET'])
def signUp():
    try:
        _name = request.form['inputName']
        _email = request.form['inputEmail']
        _password = request.form['inputPassword']

        # validate the received values
        if _name and _email and _password:

        # All Good, let's call MySQL

            conn = mysql.connect()
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            _hashed_password = generate_password_hash(_password)
            cursor.callproc('sp_createUser',(_name,_email,_hashed_password))
            data = cursor.fetchall()

        if len(data) is 0:
            conn.commit()
            return json.dumps({'message':'User created successfully !'})
        else:
            return json.dumps({'error':str(data[0])})
        else:
            return json.dumps({'html':'<span>Enter the required fields</span>'})

except Exception as e:
    return json.dumps({'error':str(e)})
finally:
    cursor.close() 
    conn.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=5002)
```

Comment: Is in your source code `if _name and _email and _password:` correctly indented? Because in your example isn't.

Comment: Please, enable debug mode in `app.run`. So you can get a better error report from Flask.

Comment: yep ,it's indented correctly haven't done that in the example though, will do that now

Answer (score 0):

MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST should be the address of your *database host*, hence the name, not your web app.

Looking at [the docs](http://flask-mysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), the default is "localhost" and the matching port setting is 3306, which should be fine for your setup; you should remove your definition altogether.

Comment: got it understood, is there any way that I can access MySQL in XAMPP. in normal python I was able to use sockets, is there a way to do such a thing in flask?

Comment: Again, look at [the docs](http://flask-mysqldb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) - there's a `MYSQL_UNIX_SOCKET` setting. Note that I linked to the wrong docs above if you're actually using Flask-MySQLdb, and you appear to also have all the wrong setting names. Please follow the docs for the library you are using.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to have the solutions I need, will check it out